# Как создать лямбда выражение в своём классе?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, лямбда-выражение

подскажите, как можно метод `action()` превратить в функциональное выражение. Я почитал литературу и узнал что необходимо обозначать метод аннотацией `@FunctionalInterface`. Но что-то не особо получается.

Вот класс:

```
public class ButtonRept {

    private final StackPane pane;

    private final double widthPane = 170;
    private final double heightPane = 170;

    private final double widthButton = 150;
    private final double heightButton = 150;

    public Pane getPane() {
        return pane;
    }

    private final Button button;

    public ButtonRept() {
        pane = new StackPane();
            pane.setMinSize(widthPane, heightPane);
            pane.setPrefSize(widthPane, heightPane);
            pane.setMaxSize(widthPane, heightPane);

        button = new Button();
        button.getStyleClass().add("blue-button");

        button.setOnMouseClicked(handler -> action());

        button.setMinSize(widthButton, heightButton);
        button.setPrefSize(widthButton, heightButton);
        button.setMaxSize(widthButton, heightButton);

        pane.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    public ButtonRept(String nameButton) {
        pane = new StackPane();
            pane.setMinSize(widthPane, heightPane);
            pane.setPrefSize(widthPane, heightPane);
            pane.setMaxSize(widthPane, heightPane);

        button = new Button(nameButton);
        button.getStyleClass().add("blue-button");

        button.setOnMouseClicked(handler -> action());

        button.setMinSize(widthButton, heightButton);
        button.setPrefSize(widthButton, heightButton);
        button.setMaxSize(widthButton, heightButton);

        pane.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    public void setTextAndImage(String text, Image image) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
            root.setMinSize(widthButton, heightButton);
            root.setPrefSize(widthButton, heightButton);
            root.setMaxSize(widthButton, heightButton);
//        root.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        double precentImage = 80.00;
        double precenText = 20.00;

        ColumnConstraints column0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column0.setPercentWidth(100);

        root.getColumnConstraints().add(column0);

        RowConstraints row0 = new RowConstraints();
        row0.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
        row1.setPercentHeight(precenText);

        root.getRowConstraints().addAll(row0, row1);

        // Добавляем иконку
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        double getterImageHeight = image.getHeight();
        double getterImageWidth = image.getWidth();

        double proportions = getterImageHeight/getterImageWidth;

        getterImageHeight = (heightButton/100)*precentImage;
        getterImageWidth = getterImageHeight/proportions;

        imageView.setFitHeight(getterImageHeight-5);
        imageView.setFitWidth(getterImageWidth-5);

        StackPane wrapperImage = new StackPane(imageView);
        wrapperImage.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.add(wrapperImage, 0, 0);

        // Добавляем текст
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        label.getStyleClass().add("text-rept");

        StackPane wrapperText = new StackPane(label);
        wrapperText.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        root.add(wrapperText, 0, 1);

        // Устанавливаем root
        setGraphic(root);
    }

    public void setGraphic(Node node) {
        button.setGraphic(node);
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("Активация кнопки...");
    }
}
```

Вот его реализация:

```
public class InnerPaneRept implements InnerPane{

    public static final String NAME_BEAN = "paneRept";

    private StackPane wrapper;

    private ScrollPane scroll;

    private TilePane pane;

    private final Image imageProducts = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/Products.png"));
    private final Image imagePrices = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/Prices.png"));
    private final Image imageBuyers = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/Buyers.png"));
    private final Image imageSells = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/Sells.png"));

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        pane = new TilePane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ButtonRept button1 = new ButtonRept(){
            @Override
            public void action() {
                System.out.println("Активированная кнопка товаров...");
            }
        };
        button1.setTextAndImage("Товары", imageProducts);
        pane.getChildren().add(button1.getPane());

        ButtonRept button2 = new ButtonRept(){
            @Override
            public void action() {
                System.out.println("Активированная кнопка прайсов...");
            }
        };
        button2.setTextAndImage("Прайсы", imagePrices);
        pane.getChildren().add(button2.getPane());

        ButtonRept button3 = new ButtonRept(){
            @Override
            public void action() {
                System.out.println("Активированная кнопка закупок...");
            }
        };
        button3.setTextAndImage("Закупки", imageBuyers);
        pane.getChildren().add(button3.getPane());

        ButtonRept button4 = new ButtonRept(){
            @Override
            public void action() {
                System.out.println("Активированная кнопка продаж...");
            }
        };
        button4.setTextAndImage("Продажи", imageSells);
        pane.getChildren().add(button4.getPane());
        scroll = new ScrollPane(pane);

        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        wrapper = new StackPane(scroll);

        wrapper.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            pane.setMinWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
            pane.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
            pane.setMaxWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
        });

    }

    @Override
    public Pane getPane() {
        return wrapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему, а не то, как вы пытаетесь решить. Может у вашей проблемы есть более простое решение. И `InnerPaneRept` не может быть реализацией `ButtonRept`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лямбда выражение создается с помощью **функционального интерфейса** (интерфейса, у которого имеется всего один абстрактный метод). Вот пример:

```
public interface YourFunctionalInterface {
    void yourAbstractMethod();
    default void itIsPossibleToHaveDefaultMethods() {...};
    static void itIsPossibleToHaveStaticMethods() {...};
}
```

Использование функционального интерфейса:

```
void methodWhichAcceptsFuncInt(YourFunctionalInterface arg);
```

Теперь при вызове этого метода ему можно передать лямбда-выражение:

```
...
someInstance. methodWhichAcceptsFuncInt(() -> System.out.println("Hello World"));
...
```

Аннотация `@ FunctionalInterface` указывает компилятору, что это не простой интерфейс, а **функциональный**. И если интерфейс с данной аннотацией будет пустым или содержать больше одного абстрактного метода, будет выкинуто исключение (на этапе компиляции). Использовать аннотацию не обязательно, но это "хорошая практика".